# Warning: join(): Invalid argument Just started

Tags: php

I have had a custom online ordering system up for around 3 years and now all of a sudden I am getting this error:

```
Warning: join(): Invalid arguments passed in
```

php lines errors are on:

```
$grind51 = join(", ", $_REQUEST["grind51"]);
$grind56 = join(", ", $_REQUEST["grind56"]);
$grind60 = join(", ", $_REQUEST["grind60"]);
$grind64 = join(", ", $_REQUEST["grind64"]);
$woods = join(", ", $_REQUEST["woods"]);
$hybrids = join(", ", $_REQUEST["hybrids"]);
$hybridsOffset = join(", ", $_REQUEST["hybridsOffset"]);
$iron = join(", ", $_REQUEST["iron"]);
$wedges = join(", ", $_REQUEST["wedges"]);
```

Not sure what is going on since it was working fine for a long time and nothing has changed. Could a php update cause this?

Comment: Inexplicable changes are usually caused by PHP updates ;)

Comment: Try to change `$_REQUEST` to `$_POST` or `$_GET` based on your post type method (post or get). also check by printing each array that every one have have some value or not?

Comment: if you're using `mysql_` functions; could explain it. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, like a deprecation notice.

Comment: Tried using `$_GET` with no luck and not using `mysql_` Current PHP version: 5.5.25

Comment: then check for errors everywhere PHP/SQL. something made it hiccup.

Answer (score 0):

One of the $_REQUEST is not an array. You will need to figure out exactly which line is in trouble to rectify that.

Comment: @Packy so, are you only responding to answers in the "answers" area? or have you not seen comments placed underneath your question?